# Writing a SQL view in Oracle that returns multiple rows for each row in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with two relevant columns, an ID and a VARRAY of doubles representing coordinates like this: (x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, ...). The length of this array varies from four to dozens.

I need to write a view that takes all of these rows and expands each of them into several rows with an order field, like this:

```
ID order  X   Y
 1   1    x1  y1
 1   2    x2  y2
 1   3    x3  y3
 2   1    x1  y1
 2   2    x2  y2
 2   3    x3  y3
```

Google is no help, and being someone only mediocre at SQL (and mostly in PostgreSQL), the Oracle documentation is impossible to find advanced things in.

Comment: is the number of rows to "create" per real row known/constant ?

Comment: No. I updated the question to say so

Comment: you need to show the definition of the table and the VARARRAY...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I for myself like piplined tables, heres a solution that uses it:

```
create or replace type my_res_typ as object
(
  v_id    number,
  v_order number,
  x       number,
  y       number
)
;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_res_tab AS TABLE OF my_res_typ;
/

create or replace function get_coordinates return my_res_tab
  pipelined is

  Result my_res_typ := my_res_typ(null, null, null, null);
  seq    number;
  i      integer;
begin

  for r in (select * from my_table) loop
    seq := 1;

    i := r.coordinates.first;
    while i < r.coordinates.last loop
      Result.v_id    := r.id;
      Result.v_order := seq;
      Result.x       := r.coordinates(i);
      Result.y       := r.coordinates(i + 1);

      pipe row(Result);
      seq := seq + 1;
      i   := i + 2;
    end loop;

  end loop;

  return;
end get_coordinates;
/
```

now you can query it like this:

```
select * from table(get_coordinates);
```

I used

> my_table

as the table name

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I knew must be possible. I actually stumbled across the "pipelined" thing through google, but all the examples were so trivial they didn't really show anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using PIVOT statement in sql.
here are a few links :
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx
take care

Comment: No, it can't. `Pivot` can take a several rows of data and transpose them into a single row. `Unpivot` can do the opposite, but it can't do it for data stored in a user-defined type.

Comment: it does that, only it takes user defined type as string by default9which u can cast or convert)

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that uses analytic functions alongside the `table` function to produce to desired data set without using a stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE number_list AS VARRAY(10) OF NUMBER
/

CREATE TABLE my_table(id NUMBER, coordinates number_list)
/

INSERT INTO my_table(id, coordinates)
VALUES     (1, number_list(4,5,6,7,8,9));

INSERT INTO my_table(id, coordinates)
VALUES     (2, number_list(10,11,12,13,14,15));

SELECT   id,
         coordinateset,
         SUM(CASE suborder WHEN 1 THEN coordinate ELSE NULL END) AS x,
         SUM(CASE suborder WHEN 2 THEN coordinate ELSE NULL END) AS y
FROM     (SELECT id,
                 coordinate,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY CEIL(roworder / 2)) AS coordinateset,
                 DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id, CEIL(roworder / 2) ORDER BY roworder) AS suborder
          FROM   (SELECT a.id, b.COLUMN_VALUE AS coordinate, ROWNUM AS roworder
                  FROM   my_table a, table(coordinates) b))
GROUP BY id, coordinateset
ORDER BY id, coordinateset;
```

The use of `ROWNUM` is the only thing that I'm a little unsure of. While, in a controlled environment, it seems to always use the order indicated by the `varray`, I'm not sure that this behavior is guaranteed.

Finally, to state the obvious, this is a very poor design. Even if you're dead-set against using the proper relational design of splitting the data into two tables, you'd still be better off with a `varray` of user-defined types that specifically indicates which x and y values belong together.